# I have a .json file which I can and have opened in python, but how can I extract certain pieces of information from it?

Tags: python, extract, package.json

I have a .json file which I have opened in python. However I wish to only extract the orderIds from the .json file instead of printing the whole thing. Here is my code so far:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
import 
with open('data-3.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
pprint(data)
```

and here is my .json file:

```
{'orders': [{'createdTime': '2016-02-29T23:26:32Z',
             'currentStatus': {'additionalProperties': {},
                               'customInfo': None,
                               'stateActionDescription': None,
                               'stateCode': 'DESPATCH_END',
                               'stateDescription': 'Despatch completed',
                               'stateType': 'DISPATCH',
                               'timestamp': '2016-03-02T12:47:26Z',
                               'updateId': 378379,
                               'user': 'Dave Ffitch'},
```

Comment: `for order in data['orders']: print(order['currentStatus'][whatever])`...!?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Jess/Documents/First Attempt.py", line 5, in <module>
    for order in data['orders']: print(order['currentStatus']['orderId'])
KeyError: 'orderId' @deceze

Comment: Well, yeah... **there is no `orderId` in your JSON data.**

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to accessing elements of a dictionary.

```
Json = {'A':
            {'B':['C','D','E']
              }
             }
Json['A']['B'] will give you ['C','D','E']
```